# How to pass a function pointer as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c, winapi

Ok so I have the following typedef declaration:

```
typedef void (__fastcall* INFINITYHOOKCALLBACK)(_In_ unsigned int SystemCallIndex, _Inout_ void** SystemCallFunction);
```

and I have the following function declaration:

```
NTSTATUS IfhInitialize(
_In_ INFINITYHOOKCALLBACK InfinityHookCallback);
```

So my question is how would I declare and define a CallBack function that can be passed to the above function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define it following the typedef:

```
void __fastcall MyCallback(unsigned int SystemCallIndex, void** SystemCallFunction) {
// ...
}
```

And pass it with its name:

```
IfhInitialize(MyCallback);
```

Comment: Same here, a missing calling convention. If this were C++, the compiler would reject the code. It's C, though, and the compiler won't mind the broken code.

Comment: @IInspectable You're right. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer type in question takes two parameters of type `unsigned int` and `void **` and has return type `void`.  So a function signature like the following would be compatible with this:

```
void __fastcall mycallback(unsigned int SystemCallIndex, void **SystemCallFunction);
```